# How do I keep a square wave output voltage high for a TTL application?

Tags: ac, rectifier, cables, ttl, testing

I am passing an AC signal (24 Vrms at 1K Hz) down a line through a diode of unknown bias.
[image: Comparator Circuit]

Due to uncontrollable variables in the environment, there are 4 possible outcomes:

1. Positively Rectified -> XMM1 = 5V, XMM2 = 0V
2. Negatively Rectified -> XMM1 = 0V, XMM2 = 5V
3. Open (No signal)     -> XMM1 = 0V, XMM2 = 0V
4. Unaffected Signal    -> XMM1 ~=2.5V, XMM2 ~= 2.5V

Outcomes 1, 2 and 3 are easy to work with, but outcome 4 is a problem. For outcome 4 I would prefer to have an output of XMM1 = 5V, XMM2 = 5V; however, 0V on both would be acceptable too.

I've been thinking about and experimenting with different component configurations, but I haven't found anything particularly effective. If there is a better way of going about this whole thing then please let me know of an alternative approach. This is a part of a cable tester that I'm building to detect the order of 6 conductors that need to be connected in a specific order.

Comment: This is a broad question, which may make it hard for people to come up with an answer. Please ask a question related to the design if it isn't working as intended.

Comment: Good point, I renamed the question to more accurately reflect the specific issue I was facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add peak detectors to the outputs of the comparators, then an unaffected (bipolar) signal will result in both outputs high.

Also, I think your reference voltage (V2) is miswired. It needs a common ground. And in the process of fixing that, you'll need a negative reference as well.

Comment: Oh of course! I'm embarrassed I didn't see that, especially since that's what R1 + C1 do. Thank you for the help on both issues, the simulator I'm using lets me get away with the V2 configuration, but I'll have to fix it in my physical implementation.